# Convert a List contains Tuples to formatted String

Tags: string, list, haskell, tuples

I have `[(Double, Double)]` returned list and I want to format it and return it like this `String`

```
"(Double, Double)"
```

values must convert to String mentioned above line as `Double`.

If there is more than one value in the list, it should be formatted as:

```
"(Double, Double), (Double, Double), ..., (Double, Double)"
```

Comment: What happens if your list consists of more than 1 tuple?

Comment: You're probably looking for `f xs = map show xs`, but it's difficult to tell without more information. Can you edit your post with an example of the input and output you expect? For example, what output do you expect with the input `[(1.0,2.0),(3.5,4.5)]`?

Comment: I expect `"(Double, Double), (Double, Double) , ..."` if I have more tuple in my list.

Comment: Just use the show function on the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
format yourList = intercalate ", " $ map show yourList
```

Comment: Only one suggestion: use `intercalate`, which combines `concat` and `intersperse`.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to print the specific values of the `Double`s, then `efie` gave the correct answer.  However, if you only want to show the string `"Double"`, then you would use the following answer:

```
format = intercalate ", " . map (const "(Double, Double)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native `Show` instance of the list:

```
showPairSequence :: [(Double, Double)] -> String
showPairSequence = init . tail . show
```

Comment: `init . tail`? Maybe `showPairSequence = show` will be better?

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ The original poster does not want '[' or ']'